# mySQL slow performance issue

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have been using mysql 5.1 for my application. It has been responding very slow even for very simple query.

ex: for below query it took 44.1 sec while there is only one record that is to be retrieved. the table has a total of 250 thousand rows. there are normally 50-100 connections.

`select regid, cname from dbnew.csdata where sid='4514' and cdate='18-07-2022' order by regid desc;`

Please guide me how can I improve the DBMS performance.

Comment: can you show the table info? like columns, indexes

Comment: The table has total 240 columns and Only indexing used is Primary Key that is regid.

Comment: 51 is a very old version and assuming cdate has a datatype of date you are inflicting a conversion on '18-07-2022' which is not mysql date format,; Other than that a compound index on sid,cdate may help assuming connections are not locking table (what engine is it using)

Comment: Connections are not locking the table. InnoDB is the engine in use.

Comment: like P.Salmon said, consider add an index on sid, probably (sid, cdate)

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` before your query and analyze the query plan.

Comment: Thank you for your precious suggestions. Definitely I will add the indexes. the `VARCHAR` datatype is there from the last 5 years way before I joined this project. Currently I have found a workaround by adding `limit` to the queries. So far my analysis has been pointing at the table size. **But is this table size really that big to take large time for even a simple query?**

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to compare `cdate` with some way other than with `=`, you will wish it were declared `DATE` and you used constants like `'2022-07-18'`.

Whether `cdate` is DATE or VARCHAR, the following will help that *that* query run much faster:

```
INDEX(sid, cdate, regid, cname)
```

While this suggestion should help with any version of MySQL, I strongly recommend you upgrade past 5.1 since it was End-of-life almost a decade ago.

The `ALTER TABLE` to add that index will take a long time due to (1) how big the table is, and (2) how old the version is.

(The suggested `INDEX(sid, cdate)` from the Comments is almost as good.)